# Eclipse unable to explode jar

Tags: eclipse, jar

I am using Eclipse platform for Java development. There are pre-existing jar files which are being referenced in code (added in build path). It is very surprising for me that some of the jars are not getting recognized in eclipse i.e. Eclipse gives build errors about the classes belonging to some jars. Although I am able to unzip and view java classes from those jar files.

I further watched closely and found that these jars are not getting exploded in package explorer as well i.e. I am not able to see META-INF folder and jar classes in package explorer of eclipse. But I am able to see these thru winzip utility.

Comment: please show us some of the build errors

Comment: It says "<xyz> class cannot be resolved" even though jar containing xyz class is on class path. Eclipse is not able to explode the jar.

Comment: Eclipse is not supposed to explode any jar, it just supposed to recognize the classes inside it once they are in the classpath

Comment: Are you sure the classes that are not recognized by eclipse are in the jar and have the same path exactly? Can it be that just the class name is the same but the path is different?

Comment: Yes jar is on classpath. Please see the image in below link describing the issue.                                                      http://imgur.com/TUkQ2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking into this issue. I am able to find out root cause of this issue. Actually the jar files were copied to local windows machine from remote windows machine using clipboard. In this way, jar files are copied in ASCII mode which Eclipse or application is not able to recognize classes in it. 
Now I have copied jars using copy command in windows with /B parameter (binary mode), these are now working as expected.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. On top menu click Project->Clean..
2. If that didn't help, right click the project select Properties->java build path->Libraries and make sure the jars are added to the class path
3. If they are, go to the Order and Export tab, select your jar and press the top button to move it to the top.

If the last option worked then you might have a duplication. Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: seems to me like you have two jars which are the same, meaning you created a conflict (the fact that one jar has a different version does not matter, they both have the same classes) remove one of them.

Comment: This is happening for even those jars which are unique. I did remove one of those but still the same issue.